# Shadow DOM | airship-html-prompt-shadow | I'm not able to get in shadow DOM elements to click on buttons

Tags: javascript, xpath, playwright, shadow-dom

I'm having trouble finding the correct XPaths to click the "No, Thanks" and "Yes, Subscribe me!" buttons in the provided Airship HTML prompt. I've reviewed the documentation https://docs.airship.com/platform/web/plugins/html-prompt/ and tried using the following code:

```
<div class="airship-html-prompt-shadow">
#shadow-root (open)
<div class="airship-prompt-container" style="display: block;"><div class="airship-alert airship-position-top" data-airship-prompt="">
    <div class="airship-alert-powered airship-hidden"><a data-airship-trigger-goto-airship="">Airship</a></div>
    <div class="airship-alert-body">
      <div class="airship-alert-logo"><img src="/assets/Web/images/logo-top.svg"></div>
      <div>
        <div class="airship-alert-title">Subscribe to our notifications</div>
        <div class="airship-alert-message">Stay tunned to get our best offers by subscribing to our push notifications</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="airship-alert-buttons">
      <button class="airship-btn airship-btn-deny" data-airship-trigger-deny="">No thanks</button>
      <button class="airship-btn airship-btn-accept" data-airship-trigger-accept="">Yes, Subscribe me!</button>
    </div>
  </div></div>

</div>
```

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwoAb.png)

Code that I'm executing

```js
await landingpage.gotolandingscreen()
await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');

await page.waitForSelector('div.airship-html-prompt-shadow');
// Get the element containing the shadow DOM
const element = await page.locator('div.airship-html-prompt-shadow');
  
// Use the >> operator to access elements within the shadow DOM
const button = await element >> locator('button.airship-btn.airship-btn-deny');
  
// Click the button
await button.click();
```

Comment: What about using something like `const shadowRoot = await element.shadowRoot; const button = await shadowRoot >> locator(<your button>)` ?

Comment: Can you share the actual page you're manipulating, or a [mcve] of it? The HTML excerpt is helpful, but isn't runnable and I'm not sure I have time to go through the trouble of installing Airship, whatever that is, and building an app with it. Thanks. But yeah, `await element >> locator` isn't how `>>` is used. See [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-in-shadow-dom): "All locators in Playwright by default work with elements in Shadow DOM. The exceptions are:" ... "xpath" (which you probably shouldn't be using anyway--keep using the plain CSS selector) and "closed shadow roots".